# How to prevent auto-start programs from running in remote desktop session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11, autostart

I'm currently writing an automation script that need to be run in fullscreen mode and the computer is unusable when the script is running. After googling I found that it is possible to start a seperate session using the same account by using remote desktop.

Now the problem is when I successfully log into the another session, all the auto start apps will run again. It is annoying since they are already running. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than placing the script in a startup folder, run it as a Scheduled Task with a [specific trigger](https://gist.github.com/Iristyle/58ff446bd3f60e68d52df3868c917a0e), e.g., an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/ne-taskschd-task_trigger_type2), or with limited repetition, e.g., TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY, so that it won't repeat again in he same day.

Answer (score 0):

This idea comes from the post
[Prevent some startup programs from running when logging in to Windows Vista via Remote Desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/41903/prevent-some-startup-programs-from-running-when-logging-in-to-windows-vista-via).

The idea is to replace the startups that you don't want running
in RDP by a `.bat` file in the Startup group that will execute
them only in Console (desktop) mode:

```
@echo off
IF %SESSIONNAME% == Console (
REM List paths to programs here prefaced by "start " so they run async.
) ELSE (
REM Not in console, not executing programs.
)
```